# Why doesn't my BLC 'save' action save all records unless its at the very end of the cache insert?

Tags: acumatica

I have BLC code that is parsing out the AuditHistory 'ModifiedFields' field so that I have multiple lines with separate 'Field' and 'Value' fields.  The 'ModifiedFields' field contains null separated values, so my BLC C# code uses the split function to put these into an array.   This all works fine.  The problem I'm having is saving to a table in Acumatica via the Graph / Cache 'insert' function.  If I use the 'Actions.PressSave()' method after every iteration of the array, it doesn't save every record - effectively skipping records.  I have no idea why this would happen.  If I put the 'Actions.PressSave()' method at the very end of everything, I get all the records - but sometimes it times out, I'm assuming because of (in some cases) the massive amount of records being cached before the save.

Putting the PressSave method at ANY other point in the loop(s) results in missed records.

Here is my BLC code (note the several places I placed the PressSave method for testing, but commented out - leaving the last one):

```
public PXAction<AUAuditSetup> CreateAuditRecords;
    [PXProcessButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Audit Records", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable createAuditRecords(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
        {

            //Create graph of TAC screen...
            var osdm = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpenSourceDataMaint>();
            xTACOpenSourceDetail osd;
            int recordID = 1;


            //Get records from AuditHistory
            //PXResultset<AuditHistory> res = PXSelect<AuditHistory>.Select(Base);
            PXResultset<AuditHistory> res = PXSelect<AuditHistory, 
                                            Where<AuditHistory.changeDate, GreaterEqual<Required<AuditHistory.changeDate>>>>.Select(Base, Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2013"));

            var companyID = Convert.ToString(PX.Common.PXContext.GetSlot<int?>("singleCompanyID"));

            foreach (PXResult<AuditHistory> rec in res)
            {
                var ah = (AuditHistory)rec;
                if (ah != null)
                {
                    string[] fields = ah.ModifiedFields.Split('\0');
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.GetUpperBound(0); i+=2)
                    {
                        osd = new xTACOpenSourceDetail();
                        osd.OpenSourceName = "AuditHistoryTable";
                        osd.DataID = "1";
                        osd.String01 = Convert.ToString(PX.Common.PXContext.GetSlot<int?>("singleCompanyID"));
                        osd.Number01 = ah.BatchID;
                        osd.Number02 = ah.ChangeID;
                        osd.Number03 = recordID;
                        osd.String02 = ah.ScreenID;
                        osd.String03 = Convert.ToString(ah.UserID);
                        osd.Date01 = ah.ChangeDate;
                        osd.String04 = ah.Operation;
                        osd.String05 = ah.TableName;
                        osd.String06 = ah.CombinedKey;

                        osd.String07 = fields[i];
                        osd.String08 = fields[i + 1];

                        osd.String09 = Convert.ToString(ah.ChangeDate);

                        osdm.OpenSourceDataDetail.Insert(osd);
                        //if (osd != null)
                            //osdm.Actions.PressSave();

                        recordID++;
                    }
                    recordID = 1;
                    //osdm.Actions.PressSave();
                }
                //osdm.Actions.PressSave();
            }
            osdm.Actions.PressSave();
        });

        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would review the keys of your DAC having problems as well as make sure the key values are getting set as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

Instead of instantiating osd directly, replace with:

```
osd = osdm.OpenSourceDataDetail.Insert();
```

and then after assigning values and prior to PressSave(), use .Update on the cache:

```
osdm.OpenSourceDataDetail.Update(osd);
```

and then after PressSave(), clear the graph:

```
osdm.Clear();
```

Importantly, does your DAC have an IsKey = true on the DataID field and marked PXDBIdentity, hence auto-assigned and unique?

Example:

```
public abstract class dataID : PX.Data.IBqlField {}

[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
[PXUIField(Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
public virtual int? DataID {get; set;}
```

If the changes are successful, you could then try moving the .PressSave() and .Clear() after the For loop.